# items of arraylist being displayed as one singular item on listview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

so im making an app that stores meals eaten by the user. Im trying to display an arraylist of the quantity of food eaten  by the user as well as the name of the food. However whenever I add an item to the array list it gets displayed as one singular item on the list view.

```
    food = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    foodChoice = new ArrayList<>();
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    fAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, foodChoice);
    fAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(fAdapter);
    foodRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
           if(task.isSuccessful()){
               Map<String, Object> map = task.getResult().getData();
               for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()){
                   foodChoice.add(entry.getKey());
               }
               fAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
        }
    });

    AddFood = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AddFoodbtn);
    AddFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
                addItem();
            }
```

this is the method that adds the items to array list I think the logic error is here but i'm not too sure what Im doing wrong.

```
        private void addItem() {
            Quantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EtQuantity);
            AddFood = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddFoodbtn) ;
            amount = Quantity.getText().toString().trim();
            amountNumber = Double.parseDouble(amount);
            SelectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            food.put(SelectedItem, amountNumber);
            keySet = food.keySet();
            foodName = new ArrayList<>(keySet);
            values = food.values();
            valueString = new ArrayList<String>();
            MealList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(Double i: values){
                valueString.add(String.valueOf(i));
            }

            addFood(foodName + " " + valueString + " KG");


            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MealList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        }

        private void addFood(String item) {
            MealList.add(item);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    });







    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
          //  String name = food.get(i);
          //  makeToast(name);

        }

    });

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            return false;
        }
    });

}

public Toast toast;






@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: this is the output [link](https://ibb.co/kJsDMq8)

Comment: UPDATE I defined the adapter outside of the for loop and it now creates a new element in the list view everytime an item is added however this new element displays the entirety of the arraylist

Comment: Create adapter outside and call notifyDataSetChanged after adding item

Comment: @shockwave ive done that and now it creates a seperate element however the whole arraylist is displayed

Comment: *in the new element